# Problems with a card game - How to make card return to original position when not placed in dragzone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a problem, im very new in this thing of programming and i wont to learn a bit.

Im using Unity 2D to make a card game, they have 5 gameobjects ..card1, card2, playerarea1 and 2, and a zone where the card1 will be draged and put it in there. BUT in case that this GameObject isn´t put in this "dragzone" it would go back to the original site. In this case, Playerarea1

I let you this code here beacause this problem downed my motivation a little.

My problem is that ..when you put the card in the dropzone (ZonaCartas) it not get in there, and it does´nt go back yo the starpotition in vector2 ..it just get stucked in the cursor and cant do anything else

It´s C#

```
 public class arrastrarSoltar : MonoBehaviour

 {
    // Is dragging
    private bool estaArrastrando = false;

    private bool estaZonaCartas = false;

    private GameObject ZonaCartas;

    private Vector2 startPosition;

    void Update()
    {
        if(estaArrastrando)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        }
    }

    // Start dragging
    public void empezarArrastrar()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
        estaArrastrando = true;
    }
    
    // Finish dragging
    public void terminarArrastrar()
    {
        estaArrastrando = false;
        if (estaZonaCartas)
        {
            transform.SetParent(ZonaCartas.transform, false);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = startPosition;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Also: are you sure you mean Udemy and not Unity? I thought udemy was an online learning site.

Comment: Dude, sorry, Long day studing another things ...yes, is Unity

Comment: My problem is that ..when you put the card in the dropzone (ZonaCartas) it not get in there, and it does´nt go back yo the starpotition in vector2 ..it just get stucked in the cursor and cant do anything else

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to help since I've not sunk my teeth into Unity yet, but how does `estaZonaCartas` get set? And how does `terminarArrastrar()` get called? Same question for `empezarArrastrar()` to be honest.

Comment: You can see how he do it, im fallowing his steps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-dUB52eEMk&t=3314s ..minute 52:00 is when it start my problem

Comment: Does `terminarArrastrar` get triggered if you put a breakpoint in it?

Comment: JDormer i ..i don´t know, im really noob in this, but you can see the video i make, it´s all there, minute 51 is where it gets hard for me

Comment: @AgustínFleitas Learning how to use breakpoints will make your life much easier. 
I am guessing that your problem is that `terminarArrastrar()` is not being called 
so `estaArrastrando` does not get set back to false. Read up on breakpoints here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @JDormer thanks!! I will! i need to learn a lot